# Want to open a eclipse xml file in code and navigate to a specific line number with reference to its IFile

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-pde

I have a reference to an xml file in eclipse IDE through its IFile instance. I know want to add an action on my view that opens the file in the xml editor and navigate to a specific line number. Anyone have any ideas on how to go about this?

Comment: Where does the line number come from? User input?

Comment: comes from cdoe, based on a xml element path they select in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you know the file's URL:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = activeWorkbenchPage();
if (page == null) {
    throw new RuntimeException();
}

IFile file;
IFile[] files = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
            .findFilesForLocationURI(url.toURI());
file = files[0];

IMarker marker;
marker = file.createMarker(IMarker.TEXT);
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, lineNumber);
marker.setAttributes(map);
IDE.openEditor(page, marker);
marker.delete();
```

Of course you will need to catch/throw a couple of Exceptions as well, but I omitted this here for simplicity.