# Open an XML file in Eclipse at a specific line number

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, jface

I'm writing an eclipse pluging and I need to open an XML file at a specific line number (where the error is).

I have followed the accepted answer on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556957/want-to-open-a-eclipse-xml-file-in-code-and-navigate-to-a-specific-line-number-w) and it actually works... with the undesired side effect of generating **resourceChanged()** events in my `FileSystemChangesListener` listener.

Is there a way of jumping to the specific line without producing file changes? These events trigger other executions in the plugin.

I tried adding the `TRANSIENT` parameter as `true` to no avail as in:

```
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put(IMarker.LINE_NUMBER, lineNumber);
map.put(IMarker.TRANSIENT, true); // doesn't make any difference.
marker.setAttributes(map);
IDE.openEditor(page, marker);
```

Still generates the **resourceChanged()** event.

Comment: The  `IResourceDelta` `getFlags` call will have the `IResourceDelta.MARKERS` flag set for the `createMarker` call - so you can identify that and ignore it.

Comment: AWESOME! Thank, thanks, thanks, thanks. I've spent a whole day trying to figure this one out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `IFile.createMarker` call is generating the resource changed event, you can't prevent this.

However you can identify that this is a create marker event in the `IResourceData` you receive - the `getFlags()` method will have the `IResourceData.MARKERS` flag set.

Note that resource deltas can be merged so there may be several flags set - for example if `IResourceDelta.CONTENT` is set the file's contents have also changed.