# How to display line of a word from project, in eclipse editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, analysis

My e4 view plugin looks for a word in user's project. When this word found(i did these steps) and the user clicks this word on the view, user should see where this word in the project on default eclipse editor. I have offsets and linenumbers of this word.

How should i do this?

(if anyone know how to highlight this word on editor, i'm looking for this too.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you looked at how the Search dialog and View work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/13556957/2670892

Comment: @nitind yes i know what they are. Those aren't what i look for.

Comment: I'm looking for something similar to this link. I got what should i write. But I wanna ask, If i wrote a method to open an editor and show me the specific word in Double Click Action in view class. I tried but nothing changed and i guess it should work.
Or how/where i use a method like this? I came eclipse from Intellij Idea and now so confused to understand things like that :/
Thank you so much @greg-449 !

Comment: You say 'e4 view' at the start of the question - is this a pure e4 RCP (using an Application.e4xmi) or a 3.x compatibilty mode RCP?

Comment: Actually it's a 3.x compatibilty mode RCP.

Comment: This is to vague and broad. What do you have in this view? Show us the code you have tried for the double click - [edit] your question and provide a lot more detail,

Comment: I had solve it with some more resource and especially the link that you shared. Thanks a lot again. @greg-449