# Jump to code position programatically in Eclipse (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am writing an Eclipse plugin with a Method which returns the file (Java Class from the Workspace) and the Line of the occurrence of a String. It then displays the results in a Table-View. I want each search result to be clickable so the corresponding ".java" file is opened in an editor view, the cursor to be place and maybe, if possible, the occurrence selected.

Is there a way to jump there and place the cursor in the respective line of code and, if needed open the file beforehand.

Can I use the Link Class for this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you explain your requirement bit more. Seems like you want to open a file and jump to a line number.

Comment: This post appears to be [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as per *Questions that lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem.* Please edit your post accordingly to add sufficient detail so that people may help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/13556957/2670892